Zugzwang where the side to move must be mated in exactly 2 moves
On page 6 of this PDF, it mentions the existence of a legal position such that whoever moves first must be checkmated in exactly 2 moves. Can someone please show me this position?

Noam himself passes through here from time to time, so maybe he can supply his original answer to the task

As Laska suggested, I was able to find it
in my 2001 files of correspondence with Richard Stanley:
[Title "Whoever moves must get mated in 2 moves (NDE 2001)"]
[FEN "BKQQ4/pPPP4/rbkp4/qrbp4/bp1p4/1p1P4/1P6/8 w - - 0 0"]

I used Black R+R instead of R+P or P+P to keep the position legal.
